# find & replace part of text

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to do a search and replace using GREP/Regex

Here is what I am searching for

```
<div align="center" class="orange-arial-11"><b>.+<br>
```

I want to remove the `<b>, <br>` tags, and place `<h3>` tags around what .+ finds.

But I can't get what .+ finds to stay when it does the replace.

For example, I want to find this

```
<div align="center" class="orange-arial-11"><b>This is the section I want intact<br>
```

to change to this

```
<div align="center" class="orange-arial-11"><h3>This is the section I want intact</h3>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) instead of grep:

```
# Modify the file in-place
sed -i~ 's|\(<div align="center" class="orange-arial-11">\)<b>\(.\+\)<br>|\1<h3>\2</h3>|' the-file
```

Comment: What about "perl -ple 's/search regex/replace string/"?
Grep has absolutely no replace functionality, only searching. Sed is the usual answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends exactly what system you're using, but if you put something in parenthesis you can refer to it later

So it might be something like

```
s/<b>(.+)<br>/<h3>\1<\/h3>/
```

Comment: I am just using the search/replace in textwrangler.

Comment: Ok, then use what I said. Text to find = <b>(.+)<br> Replace with: <h3>\1</h3> If you need to match the stuff at the beginning, do (foo)<b>(.+)<br> and \1<h3>\2</h3>

Answer (score 0):

In TextWrangler:

search for:

```
<div align="center" class="orange-arial-11"><b>(.+?)<br>
```

replace with:

```
<div align="center" class="orange-arial-11"><h3>\1</h3>
```

The '\1' will be replaced with the string matched inside the parens in the search pattern.

Comment: (Also, using the question mark (.+?) instead of (.+) will ensure that you don't match too much -- otherwise, (.+) might match everything up to the last <br> in the text)